# Converting a loop from x86 assembly to C language with AND, OR, SHR and SHL instructions and an array

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, reverse-engineering

I don't understand what is the problem because the result is right, but there is something wrong in it and i don't get it.

1.This is the x86 code I have to convert to C:

```
%include "io.inc"  
SECTION .data
mask    DD      0xffff, 0xff00ff, 0xf0f0f0f, 0x33333333, 0x55555555

SECTION .text
GLOBAL CMAIN
CMAIN:
    GET_UDEC        4, EAX
    MOV             EBX, mask
    ADD             EBX, 16
    MOV             ECX, 1
.L:
    MOV             ESI, DWORD [EBX]
    MOV             EDI, ESI
    NOT             EDI
    MOV             EDX, EAX
    AND             EAX, ESI
    AND             EDX, EDI
    SHL             EAX, CL
    SHR             EDX, CL
    OR              EAX, EDX
    SHL             ECX, 1
    SUB             EBX, 4
    CMP             EBX, mask - 4
    JNE             .L

    PRINT_UDEC      4, EAX
    NEWLINE
    XOR             EAX, EAX
    RET
```

2.My converted C code, when I input 0 it output me the right answer but there is something false in my code I don't understand what is:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void)
{
    int mask [5] =  {0xffff, 0xff00ff, 0xf0f0f0f, 0x33333333, 0x55555555};


    int eax;
    int esi;
    int ebx;
    int edi;
    int edx;
    char cl = 0;
    scanf("%d",&eax);
    ebx = mask[4];
    ebx = ebx + 16;
    int ecx = 1;
    L:
    esi = ebx;
    edi = esi;
    edi = !edi;
    edx = eax;
    eax = eax && esi;
    edx = edx && edi;
    eax = eax << cl;
    edx = edx >> cl ;
    eax = eax || edx;
    ecx = ecx << 1;
    ebx = ebx - 4;

    if(ebx == mask[1]) //mask - 4
    {
        goto L;
    }

    printf("%d",eax);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a complete question with your own attempt and a detailed error description.

Comment: @fuz i am new here but im very thankfull for ur help and doing  everything to make easy for u to understand my problem and waste a minimum of ur time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assembly AND is C bitwise  `&`, not logical `&&`**.  (Same for OR).  So you want `eax &= esi`.

(Using `&=` "compound assignment" makes the C even *look* like x86-style 2-operand asm so I'd recommend that.)

NOT is also bitwise flip-all-the-bits, not booleanize to 0/1.  In C that's `edi = ~edi;`

Read the manual for x86 instructions like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/not, and for C operators like `~` and `!` to check that they are / aren't what you want.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic

You should be single-stepping your C and your asm in a debugger so you notice the *first* divergence, and know which instruction / C statement to fix.  Don't just run the whole thing and look at one number for the result!  Debuggers are massively useful for asm; don't waste your time without one.

---

**CL is the low byte of ECX**, not a separate C variable.  You could use a union between `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` in C, **or just use `eax <<= ecx&31;`** since you don't have anything that writes CL separately from ECX.  (x86 shifts mask their count; that C statement could compile to `shl eax, cl`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr).  The low 5 bits of ECX are also the low 5 bits of CL.

`SHR` is a logical right shift, not arithmetic, so you need to be using `unsigned` not `int` at least for the `>>`.  But really just use it for everything.

---

**You're handling EBX completely wrong; it's a pointer.**

```
 MOV             EBX, mask
 ADD             EBX, 16
```

This is like `unsigned int *ebx = mask+4;`

The size of a dword is 4 bytes, but C pointer math scales by the type size, so `+1` is a whole element, not 1 byte.  So 16 bytes is 4 dwords = 4 `unsigned int` elements.

```
MOV             ESI, DWORD [EBX]
```

That's a load using EBX as an address.  This should be easy to see if you single-step the asm in a debugger: It's not just copying the value.

```
CMP             EBX, mask - 4
JNE             .L
```

This is NASM syntax; it's comparing against the *address* of the dword before the start of the array.  It's effectively the bottom of a fairly normal do{}while loop.  ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump))

```
do {          // .L
   ...
} while(ebx != &mask[-1]);    // cmp/jne
```

It's looping from the end of the `mask` array, stopping when the pointer goes past the end.

Equivalently, the compare could be `ebx !-= mask - 1`.  I wrote it with unary `&` (address-of) cancelling out the `[]` to make it clear that it's the address of what would be one element before the array.

Note that it's jumping on *not* equal; you had your `if()goto` backwards, jumping only on equality.  This is a loop.

---

`unsigned mask[]` should be `static` because it's in `section .data`, not on the stack.  And not `const`, because again it's in `.data` not `.rodata` (Linux) or `.rdata` (Windows))

This one doesn't affect the logic, only that detail of decompiling.

---

There may be other bugs; I didn't try to check everything.

Comment: thank u very much Peter but i dont know unions as good as i have to for this code  so despite using   eax = eax << cl;
                       edx = edx >> cl ; i have to use eax = eax << ecx and edx = edx >> ecx ??

Comment: @FARCRY3: That would be one way to express it.  See my updated answer, though; the most accurate way is `eax <<=  ecx&31;`

Comment: @PeterCordes  i dont get this pls say it one more time                                                       do {          // .L
   ...
} while(EBX != &mask[-1]);    // cmp/jne

Comment: @FARCRY3: The asm `.L: ... cmp/jne .L` is equivalent to a C `do{ ... }while()` loop.  The loop condition is comparing the address.  I updated that text again recently to say it more clearly.  In C, `&mask[-1]` is the address 4 bytes before the start of the array.  (It's actually undefined behaviour to write it that way; you could write `}while(EBX + 1 != mask)` or `}while(ebx-- != mask)` to also fold in the decrement.  **Use a debugger** to single-step the asm version and watch registers change.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ebx != mask[1]) //mask - 4
{
    goto L;

}
```

//JNE IMPLIES a !=

Comment: Note that it's actually `&mask[-1]` comparing a pointer; this is apparently NASM syntax.